# From the equation $|z-a|=|z-b|$ in the complex plane, obtain the slope-intercept equation of the line

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I want, by the use of the equation of the line in complex plane, to find the slope and x intercept in x-y plane. Attempt:

$$|z-a|=|z-b|$$
$$y=mx+h$$
$$m=m(ax,ay,bx,by) \quad h=h(ax,ay,bx,by)$$
$$a=ax+iay \quad b=bx+byi$$

How to find $m$ and $h$ here?

Answer (score 0):

You start with
$$
|z-a| = |z-b|   \iff |z-a|^2 = |z-b|^2
$$
write the squared modulus as $|w|^2 = w\bar w$:
$$
(z-a)(\bar z - \bar a) - (z-b) (\bar z-\bar b) = 0
$$
expand
$$
z\bar z - a \bar z -\bar a z + a \bar a - z\bar z + b \bar z +\bar b z - b \bar b = 0
$$
cancel the quadratic term and collect
$$
(b-a)\bar z +(\bar b - \bar a)z + |a|^2 - |b|^2 = 0
$$
now notice that $2 \Re w = w + \bar w$, so
$$
2\Re ((\bar b-\bar a)z) + |a|^2 - |b|^2 = 0
$$
and by letting
$$
a=a_x + i a_y, \qquad b = b_x + i b_y, \qquad z = x + iy
$$
you get
$$
2(b_x-a_x) x - 2(b_y-a_y)y + |a|^2 - |b|^2 = 0
$$
and finally,
$$
y = \frac{b_x-a_x}{b_y-a_y} x + \frac{|a|^2-|b|^2}{2(b_x-a_x)}.
$$