# Modulus equation- What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm trying to algebraically find the equation of the perpendicular bisector of line joining (-3+2i) (3-2i). I'm Trying to use the identity z x z*=|z|^2 but u keep getting the solution **x+iy=0** Instead of an equation. Can anyone pls point out my error

For reference, I am using this method [From the equation $|z-a|=|z-b|$ in the complex plane, obtain the slope-intercept equation of the line](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/754508/from-the-equation-z-a-z-b-in-the-complex-plane-obtain-the-slope-intercept)

[image]

Comment: You should translate this into latex, remind for the next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation to solve is
$$
|z+3-2i|=|z-3+2i|
$$
Squaring and using $|w|^2=w\bar{w}$, you get
$$
(z+3-2i)(\bar{z}+3+2i)=(z-3+2i)(\bar{z}-3-2i)
$$
This yields
$$
z\bar{z}+(3-2i)\bar{z}+(3+2i)z+13=z\bar{z}+(-3+2i)\bar{z}+(-3-2i)z+13
$$
hence
$$
(3+2i+3+2i)z+(3-2i+3-2i)\bar{z}=0
$$
that becomes
$$
(6+4i)z+(6-4i)\bar{z}=0
$$
This means that the number $(6+4i)z$ is purely imaginary, so you can express the solutions as
$$
z=\dfrac{26ki}{6+4i}=\frac{13ki}{3+2i}=ki(3+2i)=k(-2+3i)
$$
with real $k$. In standard coordinates this is the line $3x-2y=0$.

---

Where is your error? You get
$$
3(z+\bar{z})+2(z-\bar{z})i=0
$$
but this isn't a representation of a complex number as real part plus $i$ times the imaginary part: indeed $z-\bar{z}$ is a purely imaginary number, so $(z-\bar{z})i$ is *real*.

If you write $z=x+yi$, then the relation becomes
$$
6x+2(2yi)i=0
$$
hence $6x-4y=0$, which is the same as $3x-2y=0$ as found above.

Comment: Ohh. So my mistake was equating the “real” and “imaginary” parts to zero when the were the other way around. Thank you so much for the answer; I would have never spotted this mistake and would have continued to do this without much thought.

Comment: @OVERWOOTCH I use to surprise my students when proving the triangle inequality: I arrive at $(w\bar{z}-\bar{w}z)^2\le0$ and tell them this is obviously true. Then I wait for objections.  It's the same: the number in parentheses is purely imaginary because it equals the negative of its conjugate.

Comment: Lol. Im aware the difference of 2 conjugates is purely imaginary but it never crossed my mind to check. I should really start thinking about what im actually doing.